# html table issue with for-loops

Tags: python, html, html-table

I'm having a difficulty formatting a table in html through python.  I'm using for-loops from previous information, and the first two columns have been formatted, but I'm having difficulty placing certain values in the right place.

## the part of my code determining the second column:

```
for c in sorted(max_films):
    print "<tr><th>"
    print c
    print "<td>"
    print max_films[c]
    print "</td></tr>"
```

## should be producing the third

```
for c in max_list1:
    print "<tr><th>"
    print "<td>"
    print c
    print "</td></tr>"
```

This is the table it is producing:

- Year  Highest Grossing Film   Most Similar    2nd Most Similar    3rd Most Similar
- 2000  The Sixth Sense
- 2001  Star Wars: Episode I - The Phantom Menace
- 2002  Harry Potter and the Sorcerer's Stone
- 2003  The Lord of the Rings: The Two Towers
- 2004  The Lord of the Rings: The Return of the King
- 2005  Star Wars: Episode III - Revenge of the Sith
- 2006  Pirates of the Caribbean: Dead Man's Chest
- 2007  Pirates of the Caribbean: At World's End
- (blank)The Perfect Storm
- (blank)Planet of the Apes
- (blank)The Lord of the Rings: The Fellowship of the Ring
- (blank)Spirited Away
- (blank)Collateral
- (blank)Troy
- (blank)The Chronicles of Narnia: The Lion the Witch and the Wardrobe
- (blank)300

The films(Perfect Storm - 300) should be aligned in the third column instead of under the second.  How can i fix this??

full html code:

```
print "Content-Type: text/html"
print ""
print "<html>"
print "<body>"
print "<table border=1>"

print "<tr>"
print "<th><font color=black>Year</font></th>"
print "<th><font color=blue>Highest Grossing Film</font></th>"
print "<th><font color=red>Most Similar</font></th>"
print "<th><font color=red>2nd Most Similar</font></th>"
print "<th><font color=red>3rd Most Similar</font></th>"
print "<th><font color=red>4th Most Similar</font></th>"
print "</tr>"


for c in sorted(max_films):
    print "<tr><th>"
    print c
    print "<td>"
    print max_films[c]
    print "</td></tr>"


for c in max_list1:
    print "<tr><th>"
    print "<td>"
    print c
    print "</td></tr>"

print "</body>"
print "</html>"

sorted(max_films) = ['2000', '2001', '2002', '2003', '2004', '2005', '2006', '2007']

max_list1 = ['The Perfect Storm', 'Planet of the Apes', 'The Lord of the Rings: The Fellowship of the Ring', 'Spirited Away', 'Collateral', 'Troy', 'The Chronicles of Narnia: The Lion the Witch and the Wardrobe', '300']
```

Comment: Your HTML is invalid (tags don't match).

Comment: This is pretty irritating. can you post the complete code sample? You shouldn't create table rows in both loops. Also I see the table header never gets closed. In addition I don't understand what data `c` contains at which point. Should look something like `for (...) print "<td>data[0]</td><td>data[1]</td>` etc.

Comment: `for c in sorted(max_films):
        print "<tr><th>"
        print "<td>c</td>"
        print "<td>max_films[c]</td>"
        print "</th></tr>"`

try it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Errors

- You should not use table rows (tr elements) for columns!
- You do not close open headers (th elements)
- You should use table headers in the head onlym not in the content rows!

### Valid table structure

```
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>Year</th>
            <th>Highest Grossing Film</th>
            <th>Most Similar</th>
            <th>2nd Most Similar</th>
            <th>3rd Most Similar</th>
        </tr>

    <!-- create rows in a loop -->
    <tr>
        <td> ... </td>
        <td> ... </td>
        <td> ... </td>
        <td> ... </td>
        <td> ... </td>
    </tr>
    <!-- loop this ^^ -->

</table>
```

See sample: http://jsfiddle.net/n2w5D/

### General solution

You cannot loop over columns when creating tables, because you need to write all table cells of a row into one row. The structure of a table is based on rows as parent element not on columns!
You will need to have the data for each row to procude something like this:

```
print "<table>"

print "<tr>"
    // print your caption row
    print "<th> Year </th>"
    print "<th> Highest Grossing Film </th>"
    print "<th> Most Similar </th>"
    print "<th> 2nd Most Similar </th>"
    print "<th> 3rd Most Similar </th>"
print "</tr>"

// loop data
for row_data in data:
    print "<tr>"

    // print data (maybe: row_data[0] == year, row_data[1] == movie name etc.)
    for cell_data in row_data:
        print "<td>"
        print cell_data
        print "</td>"

    print "</tr>"

print "</table>"
```

### Solution for your case

After you posted your full code, I think you didn't mean columns, but rows!
I think this is what you want:

```
for c in sorted(max_films):
    print "<tr><td>"
    print max_films[c]
    print "</td>"

for c in max_list1:
    print "<td>"
    print c
    print "</td></tr>"
```